# Trabalhando com valores no C#?

Tags: c#

Estou procurando a maneira correta de trabalhar com valores no C#. Em Java eu uso BigDecimal mas no C# pelo que pesquisei não encontrei nada parecido. Alguns exemplos que encontrei falam pra usar `double` ou `float` ou apenas `decimal` mesmo.

Minha pergunta é, para valores qual o ideal de ser usado ?

Comment: Acredito que vai de acordo com o limite desse `BigDecimal`. `Float` têm a precisão de 7 dígitos, enquanto o double têm precisão de 15-16 dígitos se não me engano. Vai de acordo com o que você deseja usar. Mas se for pra armazenamento relacionado a `money`, o mais indicado vai ser o `decimal`.

Comment: @DanielNicodemos obrigado.